# strings in python

Tags: python, string, variables, input

I've got a problem. i have to write a program that asks the first name and saves it,then it has to ask the last name and do the same and then it has to write first name and last name in two rows like this:

```
    enter first name:
     x
    enter last name:
     y
     x
     y
```

for the first part i used raw_input and stored the data in firstName and lastName but i don't really now how to get to the last part.Maybe writing the two variables whould help but i don't think that it asks that
greetings from italy

Comment: i took it from opencourseware the problem 0 of 6.00 EECS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just simply print the strings.

```
firstStr = 'hello'
secondStr = 'world'
print my_str
print secondStr
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see the `print` Python built-in. And really start reading *any* reference text on the language.

Comment: i read many of them,including the wiki,if I'm asking here it's because i needed some help